# Getting from $A$ to $B$ (both constants) given $n$ iterations of $A*=x$. What's the ratio of $n/x$? How to express algorithmically?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ratio

For context, I created code of the form:

```
A = 0.125
n = 20
x = 1.1
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  A = A * x
}
B = A
```

But I don't necessarily always want to get to this particular $B$ value (0.8409378, unless I miscalculated) via 20 iterations. I may want to get to B via 30 iterations, with $x$ naturally needing modified. But I don't know how to modify $x$ given different values of $n$ such that I get from $A$ to $B$ every time.

How do I algorithmically find this relationship of $x:n$? What is the term for this kind of algorithm in mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the equation @the_candyman derived, yields:

$$B=Ax^n$$
$$\sqrt[n]{B}=\sqrt[n]{A}x$$
$$x=\sqrt[n]{\frac BA}$$

So as long as $A$, $B$ and $n$ are known, you can figure out what x is :)

Comment: Just saw that @Christoph wrote the answer to the question in the comments under the other answer, I hope it's okay that I fully simplified how they got there in my answer.

Comment: Thank you to all three of you! To be honest, I'm a tad embarrassed--I took calculus years ago, and this would have been rudimentary to figure out had I already known the formula form. Guess I need to work more on properly analogizing algorithms to their practical implementations! :D

Comment: You're welcome! Don't be to harsh with yourself, now you have a gained at least a few tools and a bit of intuition on how to approach solving problems such as these in the future :)

Comment: Hey Max, I'd appreciate it if you upvoted my answer it it was helpful for you :)